# Blade laravel e a performance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

No `Laravel`, utilizamos geralmente o `Blade` para poder escrever uma `view`.

Exemplo:

```
@unless($variable)
<p>Nenhum dado encontrado</p>
@else
   @foreach($variable as $v)
     <p>{{ $v }} </p>
   @endforeach
@endunless
```

Esse código é "compilado" para:

```
<?php if (! ($variable)): ?>
    <p>Nenhum dado encontrado ?>
<?php else: ?>
     <?php foreach($variable as $v): ?>
     <p>{{ $v }} </p>
     <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif?>
```

Umas dúvidas que surgiram são:

- O fato de o `Laravel` ter que converter o `Blade` para um código PHP válido, utilizando expressões regulares e afins, isso não pode implicar em perda de performance?
- Devo me preocupar mais com a facilidade de escrita do código do que com a performance nesses casos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> O fato de o Laravel ter que converter o Blade para um código PHP válido, utilizando expressões regulares e afins, isso não pode implicar em perda de performance?

Perda de performace comparada ao que? mecanismos de template geralmente trabalham da seguinte forma a primeira execução ele lê o arquivo de template e traduz para php puro criando um novo arquivo, as demais execuções serão feitas em cima desse arquivo de php puro, também possível fazer cache desse arquivo.

> Devo me preocupar mais com a facilidade de escrita do código do que
>   com a performance nesses casos?

Já tem programadores php demais se preocupando com desempenho. Na maior parte do tempo se preocupe em escrever coódigo legivel para humanos e otimize apenas os gargalos do sistema, uma possível solução é uso de cache.

Comment: +1 Simples, bonito e direto

Comment: Coisa Linda!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Isso só ocorre na primeira vez. Depois disso, um arquivo já parseado e convertido para código php é gerado e fica lá na pasta storage. Então, esse parseamento não é feito todas as vezes, exceto se você alterar a view `Blade` novamente, pois o cache de views parseadas é baseado na data de modificação do arquivo `Blade`.

Comment: +1 neto. Esqueci de adicionar essa informação na pergunta. Essa informação é bem-vinda ;)